# Draw to a picturebox using its handle

Tags: vb.net, class, picturebox, handle, gdi

I'm making a class which looks like Opengl. The most important part of this project is the place where the user draws. Until now I've usede this code to access an picturebox named Frame from a form named Cube:

```
Private Sub RenderScene()
    Dim Form_Name As Cube
        Form_Name = Cube

    If GL_GraphicsInitialized Then
        Dim InitBMP As New Bitmap(Form_Name.Frame.Width, Form_Name.Frame.Height)
        Dim LoadGraph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(InitBMP)

        For I As Double = 0 To ObjectsIndex - 1
            For J As Double = 0 To Objects(I).FaceCount - 1

                For W As Double = 1 To Objects(I).Face(J).PointCount - 1
                    With Objects(I).Face(J)
                        LoadGraph.DrawLine(Pen1, .PointVertexes(W - 1).X + Objects(I).Position.X, .PointVertexes(W - 1).Y + Objects(I).Position.Y, .PointVertexes(W).X + Objects(I).Position.X, .PointVertexes(W).Y + Objects(I).Position.Y)
                    End With
                Next

                ''Connects the last vertex with the first one
                With Objects(I).Face(J)
                    LoadGraph.DrawLine(Pen1, .PointVertexes(Objects(I).Face(J).PointCount - 1).X + Objects(I).Position.X, .PointVertexes(Objects(I).Face(J).PointCount - 1).Y + Objects(I).Position.Y, .PointVertexes(0).X + Objects(I).Position.X, .PointVertexes(0).Y + Objects(I).Position.Y)
                End With

            Next
        Next
        Form_Name.Frame.Image = InitBMP
End Sub
```

But as you can see I have to use that annoying piece of code `Dim Form_Name As Cube` and `Form_Name = Cube`. I also used the name of the picturebox. 
      But I want it to be portable so I came up with an very simple idea: I can take the handle of the picturebox (I think it's called HDC) and draw to the picturebox using that handle. 
     But I can't find any Frame.hdc property (I'm used to vb6). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could make your `RenderScene` function pass a `target` parameter that you render to.  That way it never has to directly know the name of the control.  You should also call `.Dispose` on `LoadGraph` or use a `Using` statement to clean it up; if you don't you will end up leaking resources like crazy.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Can you post some code,please?

Comment: `Private Sub RenderScene(ByRef PBox As PictureBox)` and for example when you're gonna change the image: `PBox.Image = InitBMP`.